# Smallest $x$ that satisfies $(ax)^x \le b$

Tags: real-analysis, lambert-w

I'm having a very hard time finding an explicit expression for the smallest $x$ (or something close to it, I don't need an exactly optimal solution) such that $(ax)^x \le b$ for $0 < b < 1, a > 0$ and $ax < 1$ always (I am fine with placing some restrictions on $a$).

A solution exists if and only if $a \le -\frac{1}{e\log b}$ because $(ax)^x$ is convex w.r.t. $x$ and minimized at $x = \frac{1}{ea}$. If I make the simplification of assuming $ax \le q$ for some smallest $q$ and rephrase the problem as $q^x = b$ I obtain the problem $a \log b \le q \log q$, which I can solve in terms of the Lambert W function, but this is not helpful to me because I need something more explicit (are there good approximations of the Lambert W function for negative values?)

Comment: A possible simplification of the problem: $$
(ax)^x\le b  \Leftrightarrow (ax)^{ax}  \le b^a  \Leftrightarrow z^z  \le c\quad z = ax,\quad c = b^a. 
$$ Note that $\log b<0$ if $0<b<1$, so $a \leq \frac{1}{e\log b}$ would imply $a<0$.

Comment: Ah yes, I dropped a - sign, it should be $a \le -\frac{1}{e\log b}$. Thank for your hint, it is a more concise way to arrive at $z = \frac{\log c}{W_{-1}(\log c)}$ as the minimizer. Do you know of a good upper bound for $W_{-1}(x)$ for $-\frac1e < x < 0$ so I can upper-bound $z$?

Comment: To understand what you are looking for: Why is a solution expressed in terms of Lambert function not explicit enough?

Comment: I am optimising the running time of an algorithm, which requires trading off between a lot of different factors. Bounding $W$ to something logarithmic plus some additional terms makes this much easier, and in computer science we also generally don't like to have non-explicit functions such as $W$ lying around in the final results.

Comment: You can use $$
 - 1 - \sqrt { - 2(\log ( - x) + 1)}  + (\log ( - x) + 1) < W_{ - 1} (x) <  - 1 - \sqrt { - 2(\log ( - x) + 1)}  + \frac{2}{3}(\log ( - x) + 1).
$$ See https://doi.org/10.1109%2FLCOMM.2013.070113.130972 Note that you need a lower bound for $W_{-1}$ to upper-bound $z$.